# Python class argument error

Tags: python, function, class, arguments

I am creating a menu but i have come across an error an would like some help as i don't know what is wrong or how to fix it, the piece of code says i am putting an argument in but i have not entered an argument.

```
class menu(object):

    def print_menu():
    # menu options    
        print "Main Menu:"
        print "Start"
        print "Quit"

    def user_menu():
    # users input
        menu_choice = raw_input('> ')

        if menu_choice == 'start':
            start()
        #does nothing as of yet
        elif menu_choice == 'quit':
            raise SystemExit

def start():
    pass

#initialising main menu
main = menu()

def start_up()

    main.print_menu()
    #first attempt
    main.user_menu()
    #second attempt
    main.user_menu()
    #third attempt
    main.user_menu()
    # start again to show the menu options
    start_up()


start_up()
```

please help, this is the traceback error most recent call the occurs in the  console when i run the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Engine.py", line 38, in <module>
    start_up()
  File "Engine.py", line 27, in start_up
   main.print_menu()
TypeError: print_menu() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `self` as an argument.

So it has to look like this:

```
class menu(object):

    def print_menu(self):
        # menu options    
        print "Main Menu:"
        print "Start"
        print "Quit"

    def user_menu(self):
        # users input
        menu_choice = raw_input('> ')

        if menu_choice == 'start':
            start()
        #does nothing as of yet
        elif menu_choice == 'quit':
            raise SystemExit
```

Also, I am not sure if using `class` here is needed. If I were you, I would get rid of the `menu` class and use just leave those methods.

Comment: thank you!!! i am new to classes so it seems i have careless with the most simple mistake

Comment: oh the class here is need for the project i am doing